# ICC Color profile for colorblind (deuteranomaly)

Tags: linux, color, debian, accessibility

I have [deuteranomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichromacy), and am looking for an ICC profile or dedicated piece of software which could modify the intensity of the colors green and red.

My intention is to use this on my PC which runs the latest version of Debian Linux. Android 8 has a feature like this built in, found in the settings under Accessibility > colour correction. I am reading that Gnome 2 (deprecated) had a feature like this within its accessibility settings as well, however the latest version of Gnome removed this feature.

If somehow the color filters could be extracted as usable profiles from either the old Gnome program or Android, that would satisfy my needs!

I have been searching for something like this for weeks, and all I could find was one ICC profile created by an individual for himself, and although it may have helped him, it does not seem to truly fix the difference in sight of a person with Deuteranomaly and normal color vision.

Alternatively I am willing to put in the effort and write my own ICC profile if nothing at all exists, however I am not sure how I can use the .icc format and its units (xyz decimals) to adjust the green and red colors to accurately reflect "normal color vision".